# Office 365 online email: Benefit to archiving?

Tags: office365, archiving

My organization has made O365 available.  Working from home, we access it through a browser.  I can no longer limit my email/calendar volume by hiving old things into a *.pst file for a given year, e.g., 2018.pst 2019.pst, etc.  I was told that this is what the Archive folder is for (red box in lower left corner if image below). It seems odd, since it's still kept, and still uses up space.

[image]

I normally compose text queries using syntax described at:

- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/learn-to-narrow-your-search-criteria-for-better-searches-in-outlook-d824d1e9-a255-4c8a-8553-276fb895a8da
- https://www.msoutlook.info/question/boolean-search-with-multiple-criteria

Messages that I don't want on my immediate radar, I put into folder "InboxNOT".  I don't manually navigate that sea of messages, I just use search queries to iteratively refine my searches.

For such a practice, it seems that there isn't any difference between Archive and InboxNOT.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: The default behavior of creating a .PST will move the file into a file that only exists locally on your machine.  You are indeed correct OWA does not support this process since you are viewing your inbox within a browser instead of Outlook.  What exactly is your question?  Please note "What is the benefit to archiving emails" isn't a question we can answer here at Super User.

Comment: @Ramhound: Yes, I know that O365 online doesn't support *.pst files.  Its counterpart is the Archive folder, which is present when accessing O365 using a browser.  But this still takes space on the servers.  So what is the difference between that and simply collecting messages into a folder?  That's basically the question as worded, so thanks if you can point out where I can clarify this.  In that difference probably lies the benefit and reason for archiving.

Comment: [One-click archiving allows you to quickly move messages out of the inbox to a folder of your choice.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2015/08/04/new-features-coming-to-outlook-on-the-web/).  It's an alternative to simply deleting the email.  [You are basically asking the difference between Archive and Online Archive.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/archive-in-outlook-for-windows-25f75777-3cdc-4c77-9783-5929c7b47028?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)

Comment: Thanks for that comment. Based on it, I added an image to my post.  I believe that the options I'm asking about is not Online Archive, but rather, Archive.  I read the posts you cited, but they seem to describe the Archive folder as just another folder. So is the answer that there is no difference? If not, I won't bother with my InboxNot folder (just below Inbox), which I created early on because I didn't know what things could happen to messages in the Archive folder which I didn't control.